# I want to create e view which has gesture overlay in it and this view can be called any where outside of an app.

Tags: android, service, android-view

I have created chathead that floats on the screen but how to call the view from it. Have been searching for this from long time.
[want to make a view like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOi8P.jpg)

this is the view I have been trying to make. it has gesture Overlay in it[Gesture Magic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gesture.action&hl=en) this app is using this view

Comment: @VivekMishra  i have tried calling view through window manager but this view doesnot detect gesture overlay how to make this to use gestureoverlay?

Answer (score 1):

The concept is simple, you basically need to create a Service that will dynamically manage your view by adding/removing it to the window manager.

```
public class StandOutViewService extends Service {

    private WindowManager mWindowManager;
    private View mStandOutView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);

        mStandOutView = new View(this);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
        params.x = 100;
        params.y = 500;

        mWindowManager.addView(mStandOutView, params);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

You can check out this library to get a starting point:
https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut

Please be aware that you need to handle permissions by using:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

and for Android 6 and above you may need to instruct your users to active your service from the accessibility settings menu.

Comment: How to use Gesture OverLay with windowmanager is used this concept view is created but gestureoverlay doesnot work??? Any help

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer and thought to share with you guys hope it will help

```
        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            900,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,


            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.x=0;
    if (FloatDirections.y>700){
    params.y=FloatDirections.y-700;}
    else {
        params.y=0;
    }
    params.gravity= Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER;
    serviceRunning=true;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(FloatDirections.x)+"  "+String.valueOf(FloatDirections.y),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gesture_recognition, null);
    b11=(Button)myView.findViewById(R.id.newbtn);
    GestureOverlayView ov = (GestureOverlayView)myView.findViewById(R.id.gestures_overlay_float);
    ov.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);
```

and then use OnGesturePerformed

```
   @Override
public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView gestureOverlayView, Gesture gesture) {
  //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"hi",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mydatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PackageName(GestureName VARCHAR,PackName VARCHAR,Action VARCHAR);");
    cursor=mydatabase.rawQuery("select * from PackageName",null);

    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = store.recognize(gesture);
```